# How to use Firebase Rule exists in SubCollection in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently working on Firebase Rule and I'm also a newbie to it. I am using exists and it seems it doesn't work, probably my syntax or query isn't correct. Any Idea how it should work? I'm trying to check the document data that I encircled in red if it exist.

Edit : It seems I'll be using get() and not exist to extract the uid in the File Path base on the suggestion, my question is how to make the File Path that the field I encircled for me to use it for the condition in Firebase Rule.

[image]

Client Code

```
return Firestore.instance
    .collection('contacts')
    .document(uid)
    .setData({
  friendId: {
     “message”: {
    },
    “uid”: friendId,
  }
});
```

Firebase Security Rules

```
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /contacts/{userID}/{friendID} {
          allow read,write : if isValidToAccessContacts(userID,friendID);
        }
      }

        function isValidToAccessContacts(userId,friendID){
          return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/contacts
          /$(request.auth.uid)/$(friendID.data.uid)/{document=**}) || 

          exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/contacts
          /$(friendID.data.uid)/$(request.auth.uid)/{document=**}) || 

          exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/contacts
          /$(request.auth.uid)/$(request.auth.uid)/{document=**})
          ;
        }
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what's going on.  Please edit the quest to show the entire set of rules, the client code making the request, and the data you're working with.  We should be able to see clearly all of the values, not just variables.

Comment: I already updated all of the relevant code, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The code on the client side is working properly, I think providing only the Firebase Rules will suffice the question.

Comment: You didn't include the client code that's making the request.  We need to be able to see everything that's going on. A rule doesn't have any meaning without client code that would trigger it. Rules don't do anything at all without client code.

Comment: Client code posted.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's better to copy the code into the question instead of showing screenshots, which are difficult to read and search. Also, please show the code without variables.  We can't know for sure what the name of the collection or document you're working with.  Also: What does setData() return? Is ther an error?  Does the document get written?  What exactly isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: There are no error in the client code if I don't implement the security rule I posted above.

Comment: I editted the question to post the client code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a wildcard like this `{document=**}` using exists.   You must call out the full path of the document to check for existence.

Comment: Does removing {document=**} will suffice or do I need also to indicated the items in sub collection?  exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/contacts
          /$(friendID.data.uid)/$(request.auth.uid))

Comment: As I said, you need to call out the **full path** of the document to check.  I don't know what that is for your case.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I'll consider this as the accepted answer if you can make atleast the full path base on the Firestore data and client code I provided.

Comment: As I said, I don't know which document you're trying to check, so I can't build a path to it.

Comment: I updated the question and circle the red to indicate the document data I'm trying to check for existence.

Comment: That's not a document, that's a field in a document.  Don't use `exists()` for that.  Use `get()` to load the document and check its fields for whatever condition you want.

Comment: Then the friend_user_id is the document_id then inside that document_id has a uid field for the friend. My next question is how to properly make the get file path to it?

Comment: At this point, I think you should be putting all this information in the question itself, so we can better understand what you're actually trying to do.  It's just not clear without a good, detailed explanation.

Comment: Your question still doesn't say exactly what you want to do with the text in that field to find the documents that should be checked.

Comment: People mostly forget to use root path of documents as "/databases/$(database)/documents/"  . This notation is important for exists()